# How to create new classes with IntelliJ Plugin API?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am very new to IntelliJ Plugin Programming and mainly got to it because my current project requires me to do the same steps again and again and only having small differences.

Becauste this takes a lot of time, I decided to take like some hours once to create a plugin which does the most work for me and then save a lot of time when having these steps again.

My question is basically how I can create new class files programmatically with the IntelliJ Plugin API. I already found out how to get the content of the currently open and in editor selected file and also how to change the content, but now how to create completely new files in a specific package.

To be honest, I think there must be something in the documentation but I already wasted like 1 hour for googling without any success. So I hope some of you guys are already experienced in creating plugins for IntelliJ Platform and maybe you can send me a good handbook or reference. I don't think that I have to write a lot of plugins but sometimes, they can really help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend to look into existing plugins, or IntelliJ source.

Comment: While waiting for answers, I was already looking through the source code of the community edition but so far, I didn't find anything about class creation. And I don't know any plugins that create java classes.

Comment: com.intellij.ide.actions.CreateClassAction#doCreate

Comment: Nice, that's the right direction. This method is protected though, but I try to find the highest level from which it is called, maybe that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use it "as is"? Then you won't need to override it, and the protected/final aspect won't worry you.

Comment: You can refer this post  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206771665-Creating-a-new-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see Meo's tip for `com.intellij.ide.actions.CreateClassAction#doCreate`.

The code does the following:

```
return JavaDirectoryService.getInstance().createClass(dir, className, templateName, true);
```

And from here we can see different signatures in [JavaDirectoryService](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/11.0/com/intellij/psi/JavaDirectoryService.java)

Perhaps this one might be relevant:

```
public abstract PsiClass createClass(@NotNull PsiDirectory dir, @NotNull String name) throws IncorrectOperationException;
```

Comment: More detailed explanation https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206771665-Creating-a-new-class